# How to solve a Pell equation using continued fractions

Tags: pell-type-equations

According to this [Mathworld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html) as well as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Fundamental_solution_via_continued_fractions), you can solve a Pell equation by generating the continued fraction convergents for $\sqrt{N}$. I wanted to do this, so I tried writing a program to solve the following Pell equation:

$p^2 - 13q^2 = 1$

I already knew the answer off the top of my head, $p=649$ and $q=180$. This is the minimal solution in $p$. But when I ran my program, nowhere did I find the $p_n/q_n$ convergent $649/180$. Instead, I found this.

```
Convergents (p/q) for the square root of 13.

p[0] = 3     q[0] = 1
p[1] = 4     q[1] = 1
p[2] = 7     q[2] = 2
p[3] = 11    q[3] = 3
p[4] = 18    q[4] = 5
p[5] = 119   q[5] = 33
p[6] = 137   q[6] = 38
p[7] = 256   q[7] = 71
p[8] = 393   q[8] = 109
p[9] = 2614  q[9] = 725
```

I believe these are the correct convergents... I double-checked. But nowhere do I find the correct answer, $p_n/q_n = 649/180$. Could someone tell me what's wrong with my approach? Is my understanding of Pell equations a little off?

Comment: Are you sure that your continued fractions are correct? http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/cfCALC.html shows for $\sqrt{13}$ the approximations $7/2, 11/3, \ldots, 393/109, 649/180, \ldots$.

Comment: You're right, my continued fractions are only right up until 393/109.

Comment: You placed the second 6 one place early.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$  
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 3 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 & \\
\frac{0}{1} & \frac{1}{0} & & \frac{3}{1} &  &  \frac{4}{1} & &  \frac{7}{2}  & & \frac{11}{3} & &  \frac{18}{5} & &   \frac{119}{33}  & &   \frac{137}{38}  & &   \frac{256}{71}   & &   \frac{393}{109}  & &   \frac{649}{180}   & &   \frac{4287}{1189}  \\
              \\
-13 & 1 & & -4 &  &  3 & &  -3  & & 4 & &  -1 & &   4  & &   -3  & &   3   & &   -4  & & 1   & &  -4  
\end{array}
$$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy$ cd Cplusplus
    jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell 13


0  form   1 6 -4   delta  -1
1  form   -4 2 3   delta  1
2  form   3 4 -3   delta  -1
3  form   -3 2 4   delta  1
4  form   4 6 -1   delta  -6
5  form   -1 6 4   delta  1
6  form   4 2 -3   delta  -1
7  form   -3 4 3   delta  1
8  form   3 2 -4   delta  -1
9  form   -4 6 1   delta  6
10  form   1 6 -4

 disc   52
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
109  720
180  1189


 Pell automorph 
649  2340
180  649

Pell unit 
649^2 - 13 * 180^2 = 1 

=========================================

Pell NEGATIVE 
18^2 - 13 * 5^2 = -1 

=========================================

  4 PRIMITIVE 
11^2 - 13 * 3^2 = 4 

=========================================

  -4 PRIMITIVE 
3^2 - 13 * 1^2 = -4 

=========================================

13       13

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus
```

Comment: I see. My program must be wrong. It only gets the correct convergents up until 393/109.

Comment: FWIW, WolframAlpha can handle continued fractions. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContinuedFraction%5BSqrt%5B13%5D%2C+20%5D http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FromContinuedFraction%5B%7B3%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C6%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%7D%5D I have no idea why the MathWorld pages don't explain how to do what they talk about in Mathematica...

Comment: @SteveKass, variant of continued fractions that requires no decimal accuracy or cycle detection; I briefly describe the middle part of the method in http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/23/binary-quadratic-forms-over-the-rational-integers-and-class-numbers-of-quadratic-%EF%AC%81elds/