# Generalized Pell equation $x^2-2y^2=49$

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

> How can I find the integer solutions of the generalized Pell equation $x^2-2y^2=49$

I have an algorithm, but this only works if $D\ge r^2+\frac{\left(|r|+1\right)}2$, (where $x^2-Dy^2=r^2$).

The problem is we've covered Pell equation and elementary number theory a couple of weeks ago, since then we're doing some algebraic number theory, but I cannot find any useful theorems there.

One solution by guessing is $(r,s)=(11,6)$ and the minimal solution to $x^2-2y^2=1$ is $(t,u)=(3,2)$ and then a second solution can be found $(x,y)=(rt+Dsu,ru+st)=(57,40)\dots$, but these are not all, am I wrong ?

Comment: There are several posts at MSE concerning Pell's equation, e.g., see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1219421/how-to-solve-a-pell-equation-using-continued-fractions?rq=1) for solving it.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde but without software and as I wrote the algorithm in the link does not work for me

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238587

Answer (score 4):

There is a method which gives all solutions, presented in [CONWAY](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/conwaysens.pdf), chapter I. It is quick enough for targets of modest absolute value such as $49.$ The $(x,y)$ pairs in Conway's diagram are given more attention in [STILLWELL](https://books.google.com/books?id=LiAlZO2ntKAC&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=john%20stillwell%20quadratic%20forms&source=bl&ots=Pq08O7zsb2&sig=YO4MT9wONXJ3RX_Lb32lutbTVLE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=y3TSVKz_LofYoAT6qYHABg&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=john%20stillwell%20quadratic%20forms&f=false), especially pages 87-100. I put those, as column vectors, in black in the first diagram, then light green in the second diagram.

To get quickly to the end, there are three families of solutions 
$$ (7,0), \; (21,14), \; (119,84), \; (693, 490),    $$ 
$$ (9,-4), \; (11,6), \; (57,40), \; (331, 234),    $$
$$ (9,4), \; (43,30), \; (249,176), \; (1451, 1026),    $$
In all three cases there are linked recursions
$$ x_{n+1} = 3 x_n + 4 y_n,  $$
$$ y_{n+1} = 2 x_n + 3 y_n.  $$

These give, by Cayley-Hamilton, separate recursions,
$$ x_{n+2} = 6 x_{n+1} - x_n. $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 6 y_{n+1} - y_n. $$

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a fast and simple algorithm to solve the generalised Pell equation
$$
x^2-Dy^2=N,
$$
with $D>0$ not a square, and nonzero integer $N$, see the article [Solving the generalized Pell equation $x^2 − Dy^2 = N$](https://nanopdf.com/download/solving-the-generalized-pell-equation-x2-dy-2-n-introduction_pdf) by John P. Robertson. It gives several algorithms and online solvers (if you do not have software), among them the PQa algorithm and LMM algorithm.

Comment: aha I also found the same paper, on page $12$ there is some geometrical approach, but this is also tedious, I think in my case the numbers $2$ and $49$ must have something special, thanks by the way.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, the geometric idea is also helpful, see the discussion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1256235/using-equation-of-a-line-to-find-infinitely-many-different-solutions-of-x2/1256296#1256296).

Comment: @DietrichBurde:  the link in your answer does not work for me

Comment: @J.W.Tanner This link changes all three month. I have to find a stable one.