# Solutions of the Pell-type equation $x^2-2y^2=-1$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am assigned to find solutions to the Pell-type equation $x^2-2y^2=-1$. So far, I only have $(7,5), (41,29)$ and $(239,169)$.

My question is, is there a general formula to find all its solutions? Are there infinitely many solutions? If it's possible to write Mathematica code that would find its solutions, what would the code look like?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Work in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. The solution $(7,5)$ means that $N(7+5\sqrt{2})=-1$. Therefore, all elements of the form $(7+5\sqrt{2})^{m}$, where $m$ is an odd integer will generate solutions. So yes, there are infinitely many solutions. To get all solutions just raise the fundamental unit: $(1+\sqrt{2})^m$ to odd powers $m$.

Comment: See also [Pell's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with $(1,1),$ and your examples, new $(x,y)$ solutions follow
$$ x_{n+2} = 6 x_{n+1} - x_n,   $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 6 y_{n+1} - y_n.   $$
This follows from 
$$ (x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}  ) = (3 x_n + 4 y_n \, , \; \; 2 x_n + 3 y_n)  $$
which is easier to confirm.

Recent and related, with artwork: [Generalized Pell equation $x^2-2y^2=49$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264242/generalized-pell-equation-x2-2y2-49/1265052#1265052)

Comment: Thanks @WillJagy.  Will post a comment if I encountered difficulties.